# Chrome: Setting class in jQuery is not reflected/rendered in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some elements created with jQuery that are added in a iframe. I set a class to those elements from jQuery.I have a CSS rule that matches that class.

I see in Chrome clearlly that the CSS rule was not applied and the inspector confirms me that.

I see class="messagesWrap" in the DOM, but it's not interpreted by the browser, because .removeClass("messagesWrap") is also unable to remove the class.

I use the DOM editor from Chrome ("Elements" tab from Developer Tools), I double click the class attribute of the element in order to edit it and just press enter afterward to apply the "changes" without actually changing anything. This time, the CSS selector is applied correctly.

Comment: Have you tried calling `addClass` after you append the `<div>` to the `<iframe>`?

Comment: Check the value of whatever you're calling `.removeClass()` on to see if you're actually matching the elements you want.

Comment: It's also possible adding a CSS class on an element that's not part of a document just doesn't work. As a workaround, try generating it with `class="messagesWrap"`, or adding the class *after* it's been added to an actual document.

Comment: @Inerdia That was it !!! You can't add class to a node that is not part of the DOM. Can you add it as a response, please ?

Comment: @Ben Sorry, didn't see your comment there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible adding a CSS class on an element that's not part of a document (yet) just doesn't work.

As a workaround, try generating it with class="messagesWrap", or adding the class after it's been added to an actual document.